# MyPy not ignoring `valid-type` error code for type aliases

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting, python-3.12

Python 3.12 added support for type aliases as defined in [PEP 695](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/). MyPy does not support this, as discussed in https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15238. However, any instance of a `type` statement results in a MyPy error. It isn't clear why this strategy was chosen, since lack of support of a valid feature should not be an error.

Since I am using Python 3.12 and the `type` statement, I want to disable this error. However, I am having trouble doing so.

I have tried the following ways:

- In `pyproject.toml`, I have:

  ```
  [tool.mypy]
  disable_error_code = 'valid-type'
  ```
- `type Number = int | float # type: ignore[valid-type]`. This even yields a `error: Unused "type: ignore" comment  [unused-ignore]` when MyPy is ran.
- `type Number = int | float # mypy: disable-error-code="valid-type"`

None of these work. In all three cases, I get the error:

```
error: PEP 695 type aliases are not yet supported  [valid-type]
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get MyPy to ignore any PEP 695 error? I have read the documentation here: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_codes.html#error-codes.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, mypy's implementation doesn't allow you to suppress it. You should report this as an issue. In short: With reference to the [passes of the type checker](https://github.com/python/mypy/wiki/Implementation-Overview), I believe that errors are only suppressible if they're emitted in the semantic analysis and type checking passes. In mypy, the PEP 695 errors you see are [emitted at the Python parser stage](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/eb1ee973778e3cf719948e1653db9760ea49405d/mypy/fastparse.py#L946).

Comment: Thank you for confirming this, as I actually realized the same thing (that Mypy is failing to suppress it), and I just finished filing issue https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/16607. This is pretty unfortunate that Mypy both generates an error for a valid feature it doesn't yet support *and* it doesn't allow you to ignore it.

Thank you for the additional details.